# Web Automation using Excel VBA with SeleniumBasic. I cannot access the values I have found

Tags: html, vba, selenium, webautomation

I am trying to load the messages that I find by `WDrv.FindElementsByXPath("//*[@id='divMessageLines']/div")` but I do not know how to access the individual values that I find. There are an unknown number of values for each search.

The HTML segment is:
[image]

In this example, if I do a .count I have 2 matching elements:

```
Dim cntr As Integer
cntr = WDrv.FindElementsByXPath("//*[@id='divMessageLines']/div").Count
‘cntr = 2
```

I can access each of the two values by using the div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0ztV.png) and div[2]. This is great but there will not always be two values:

```
cntr = WDrv.FindElementsByXPath("//*[@id='divMessageLines']/div[1]").Count
‘cntr = 1
```

If I could use a variable, I could loop through all the elements. But it doesn’t seem to like that.
It would be great if I could replace the div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0ztV.png) and div[2] with, for example, div[i] but, when I try this, the cntr always equals 0 so I assume it isn't working:

```
Cntr = WDrv.FindElementsByXPath("//*[@id='divMessageLines']/div[i]").Count
‘cntr = 0
```

I have this but it just does nothing and stops running the program (no error message):

```
Dim div As TableElement
Set div = WDrv.FindElementsByXPath("//*[@id='divMessageLines']/div")
```

So, I am not sure how to access the individual elements to, is there a way?

Comment: https://www.guru99.com/excel-vba-selenium.html shows how to loop over results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like

```vb
Dim itm

For Each itm in WDrv.FindElementsByXPath("//*[@id='divMessageLines']/div")
    'do something with itm
    Debug.Print itm.Text ' for example
Next itm
```

Comment: Awesome! That was just what I was looking for. Thank you so much!